# Where did "send a test push" go in the Foursquare consumer details page?

Tags: api, push, real-time, foursquare

I could swear this option was there a few weeks ago, and now I don't see it anymore.  Am I simply looking in the wrong place, or is there no way to send test pushes via the consumer details page anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The consumer details page was refreshed recently and the option was accidentally left out. It'll be added back soon.

Comment: Thanks for the response Akshay!  It it possible to get a sense of how long "soon" could be?  Not trying to be a pain, just trying to manage dev expectations for our clients.  Thanks!!

Comment: I'd be lying if I gave an actual date, but it's on the short list of the engineer who will be fixing it.

Comment: Any update on this?   Trying to integrate now and getting failed pushes.   Even though the button is not there now - is there an explicit URL I could enter to see the most recent error?